# How can I merge an incremental dataset and a snapshot dataset while retaining deleted rows?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-python-transform

I have a data connection source that creates two datasets:

- Dataset X (Snapshot)
- Dataset Y (Incremental)

The two datasets pull from the same source. Dataset `X` consists of the current state of all rows in the source table. Dataset `Y` pulls all rows that have been updated since the last build. These two datasets are then merged downstream into dataset `Z` with dataset `Z` being either dataset `X` or the most recent version of each row from dataset `Y`. This allows us to both have low latency updates and maintain good partitioning.

When rows are deleted in the source table, the rows are no longer present in dataset `X` but are still present in dataset `Y`.

What would be the best way keep these 'deleted' rows in dataset `Z`? Ideally I would also be able to snapshot dataset `Y` without losing any of the 'deleted' rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question! From what I understand, you want dataset `Z` to have only the most up-to-date rows, including the most up-to-date deleted rows. Both updated rows and deleted rows are present in `Y`. In this case, I would suggest first unioning `Y` and `X` together, so that all rows, including deleted rows are present in the union dataset. Then, use a window function over a date column in order to get the most recent version of each row. Here is an outline of the pyspark code I would suggest for this:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

window = Window.partitionBy(primary_keys).orderBy(F.col(date_column).desc())
Z = X.unionByName(Y) # union to get all columns, including deleted
Z = Z.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(window)) # rank by date created/updated
Z = Z.filter(F.col("row_num") == 1).drop("row_num") # keep only the latest version of each row
```

Note that this solution does not get around the issue of what happens if Y snapshots.